# How do I add a NULL column when SELECT'ing INTO a new table?

Tags: sql, select, null, field, select-into

I have a statement like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, MyField = NULL
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```

This does what I want with one exception:  the field I created `MyField` and filled with `NULL` is an `INT` type and I'd like it to be a `VARCHAR` type.  I don't know how to modify the same statement to create the new field with the `VARCHAR` type.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to change in table ? Sorry I really dont understand your problem

Answer (score 11):

Try replacing the `null` with

```
CAST(null as VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Make sure that also specify the SIZE of the field. `CAST(NULL as VarChar(20))` replacing 20 with the appropriate size.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT field1, field2, convert(varchar, NULL) as MyField
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```